# question about the forms of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was thinking about primes earlier and I thought of a hypothesis that I have been unable to prove. I was wondering whether it was a known theorem and whether anyone knows a proof or can prove (or disprove) it.

here it is:

**there are an infinite number of primes that satisfy the equation:**

$p \equiv a \bmod n$

for all A and N where A and N are relatively prime.

Comment: That's Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions. It's not easy to prove it.

Comment: oh sweet, thank you. do you say that to mean it has not been proven or that the proof is too advanced for this post?

Comment: Dirichlet proved it. I suspect the proof is beyond what fits in a reasonable answer on the site, but I may be wrong in that.

Comment: @maxG795: Please check the correction I applied in your equation, to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions of primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). A brief sketch of the proof is given in the article, along with a reference to [Jürgen Neukirch's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurgen_Neukirch) **Algebraic number theory** $(1999)$.